# How to refresh a component in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi im new in angular and i want to refresh a component after i add a new set of API url after the click event in the button
this is my code.
pokemons.service.ts

```
export class PokemonsService {

  private _url: string = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon";
  private _pokemonUrl: string;

  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }

  setUrl(value: string){
    this._url = value;
  }

  getUrl(): Observable<IPokemon[]>{
    return this.http.get<IPokemon[]>(this._url);
  }

  setPokemonUrl(value: string){
    this._pokemonUrl = value;
  }

  getPokemonsUrl(): Observable<IPokemonDetails[]>{
    return this.http.get<IPokemonDetails[]>(this._pokemonUrl);
  }

}
```

pokemon-search.component.ts

```
    export class PokemonSearchComponent implements OnInit {
  pokemons = [];
  pokemonUrl: string;
  constructor(private _pokemons : PokemonsService) { }

  ngOnInit(){
    this._pokemons.getUrl().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.pokemons = data;
    });
  }

  sendPokemonUrlToService(value: string){
    this._pokemons.setPokemonUrl(value);
  }

  onClick(url){
    this._pokemons.setPokemonUrl(url);
    console.log(this._pokemons);
  }

  onClickNextPokemon(url){
    this._pokemons.setUrl(url);
    console.log(this._pokemons);
  }
}
```

pokemon-search.component.html

```
    <ul *ngFor="let pokemon of pokemons.results">
    <li><button (click)="onClick(pokemon.url)">{{pokemon.name}}</button></li>
</ul>
<button (click)="onClickNextPokemon(pokemons.previous)">PREVIOUS</button>
<button (click)="onClickNextPokemon(pokemons.next)">NEXT</button>
```

thankyou so much in advance

Comment: There is no need to refresh component, Angular always keep your data binding updated. Can you please tell the issue in your code? Is it possible for you to create a stackblitz instance?

Comment: You need `rxjs-subject`. When user search for url that url goes to rxjs-subject and all other consumer of this subject gets results. This way your main data api and search api works separately with single responsibility.

Comment: its good now, but right now after i solve that i have a problem like this.

Comment: Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'ul'.

Comment: have you import ngModule in app.module.ts and common module to feature module?

Answer (score 1):

In general, your UI should be updated when data changes happened. If u are using  `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` as your change detection strategy and your data changes not reflected in your UI, U can use mark for check for that like below

```
 constructor(private _pokemons : PokemonsService,  
             private _changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit(){
    this._pokemons.getUrl().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.pokemons = data;
      this._changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
    });
  }
```

make sure your data is available  `this._pokemons.getUrl()` in this method call.

---

add your *ngFor like below. you should loop li instead of ul

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let pokemon of pokemons.results">
    <button (click)="onClick(pokemon.url)">{{pokemon.name}}</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: its good now, but right now after i solve that i have a problem like this. "Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'ul'." can you please help me? i alr add the BrowserModule and still nothings happening

Comment: `*ngFor` should be in `li` not `ul`